# Заполнить динамически созданные контролы данными из DataTable - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть обьект `DataTable table` с неизвестным заранее числом столбцов и строк в каждом столбце. На форме динамически создаются `groupBox` (1 box на 1 столбец) и в каждый `groupBox` заливаются `Radiobutton` (1 button на одну не пустую строку из столбца) с соответствующим `Text`.
Собственно, создать `groupBox` было не сложно, а вот как создать в них радио-кнопки, я пока не придумал.

Код:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)       
            {

                GroupBox GBstyleName = new GroupBox();
                GBstyleName.Text = table.Columns[i].ToString();
                GBstyleName.Tag = i;
                GBstyleName.AutoSize = true;
                flowLayoutPanelStyles.Controls.Add(GBstyleName);

                RadioButton RB = new RadioButton();
                RB.Margin = new Padding(10, 5, 5, 5);


                    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
                    {
                    if (table.Rows[j][i].ToString() != string.Empty)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow rw in table.Rows)
                        {
                            RB.Text = table.Rows[j][i].ToString();
                            RB.Location = new Point(10, 45 + (10 * j));
                            GBstyleName.Controls.Add(RB);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Заполняется только одно значение, последняя ячейка из `table`. Создаётся только 1 радиокнопка, хотя строк в каждом столбце больше.

Буду благодарен за совет. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы добавляете одну и ту же кнопку, переназначая ей свойства `Text` и `Location`, в двойном(?) цикле по записям таблицы.

```
for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)       
{
  GroupBox GBstyleName = new GroupBox();
  GBstyleName.Text = table.Columns[i].ToString();
  GBstyleName.Tag = i;
  GBstyleName.AutoSize = true;
  flowLayoutPanelStyles.Controls.Add(GBstyleName);

  for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
  {
    if (table.Rows[j][i].ToString() != string.Empty)
    {
      RadioButton RB = new RadioButton();
      RB.Margin = new Padding(10, 5, 5, 5);
      RB.Text = table.Rows[j][i].ToString();
      RB.Location = new Point(10, 45 + (10 * j));
      GBstyleName.Controls.Add(RB);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Так и думал что какую то мелочь упустил. Теперь работает

Comment: @Сергей если работает, отметьте ответ зеленой галочкой.